# Node + Express repeatedly firing/looping requests although result has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried almost everything, and my mind has now finally given up. Hence, I'm here asking for directions. How on earth can this simple piece of code (let's call it `app.js`):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res) {
  console.log('Request made')
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

When run like `node app.js` result in the following outcome in my terminal, considering the fact that I've only hit `localhost:3000` *once*:

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
Request made
Request made
Request made
Request made
Request made
Request made
Request made
...continues...
```

For some reason I end up with "Request made" being repeated again and again although the request is done and delivered to the browser.

The same is true if I use `app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... })` instead of `app.use(function(req, res) { ... })`.

If I turn to something more specific, like `app.get('/', function(req, res) { ... })` the repetition stops and I get *one* "Request made" as expected. However, I need to match all incoming requests - in my app I'm doing something way more complicated than logging "Request made" :)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Node: 8.11.2
Express: 4.16.3

Comment: Those are probably responses to your browser looking for favicons, etc.  Do `console.log(req.url)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Interesting indeed. My terminal now looks like this instead:

`Example app listening on port 3000!
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json
/json/version
/json ...continues...` - without me visiting `localhost:3000` that is.

Comment: Open up Devtools and click 'Network Requests'. You should be able to narrow down if the request if coming from the browser. If it isn't originating from the browser you may have a program calling that URL. 

Good news is this isn't related to Express rather your local environment.

Comment: It sounds like *something* on your network is probing http port 3000 for json or version information.

Comment: Doh... turns out that among the 88 tabs I have open there was one tab, which was pointing at localhost:3000. In this tab a devbuild of another app was running and that devbuild was constantly pinging localhost:3000 for updates (hence the /json and /json/version endpoints). Damn tabs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something and then pass the results to next callback instead of sending a response which makes it recursive since it's intercepting a response and then doing the same causing a loop.

```
// this middleware will not allow the request to go beyond it
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.send('Hello World');
});

// requests will never reach this route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome');
});
```

You need to call `next()` to  invoke middleware

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  try {
      // do something and return result
      res.send('Welcome');
  } catch(e) {
      next(e)
  }

});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('Error occurred')
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
});
```